# How is correct to insert variable in include()?

Tags: php

My method is not working:

```
<?php include ('' . echo get_template_directory() . '/member_nav.php'); ?>
```

why?

Comment: Echo sends the data to the screen. Remove that, and the unnecessary `'' .`

Comment: You should be getting an unexpected T_ECHO notice.